# Can my 70” tv stand hold 330lbs

Tags: wood, strength

Trying to see if my 70” TV Stand would support a 29 gal fish tank - about 330lbs? There is no weight capacity in the specs but it’s very sturdy. My concern is that there is no support in the middle where the tank would sit. See attached pics[image] [image]

Comment: Is it wood or particle board?

What does the back look like?

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  What is the footprint dimension of the tank?  Do the vertical supports for the center shelves extend to the floor or end at the lower shelf?  How thick is the back panel and does it extend to the floor?  If the inner panels and back extend to the floor, it should be strong enough, otherwise let us know and we can suggest how to reinforce the stand.

Comment: The dimensions of tank are 32.25 IN L X 14.25 IN W X 20.63 IN H. The vertical supports stop at the lower shelf. The back is made of particle board and also stops at the lower shelf. It’s made of engineered wood & metal

Comment: Correction: the back panel is Masonite material

Comment: As has been mentioned a couple of times in the last year, we get these sorts of queries every now and then and do bear in mind that to a degree the feedback you'll get is guesswork. It may be educated guesswork, but you'll want to assess for yourself if any reinforcements you may do have fully (and I mean *fully*) addressed any instability. I suggest you and a couple of friends sit on it, scootch together and see if there's ANY wiggle side to side..... and I guess forward and backward too, although I think (i.e. it's my guess) that this is unlikely.

Comment: I think it definitely needs to have a support in the middle. 

Just note that as someone who used to have a fish tank, if this furniture is important to you, it WILL get trashed. If it's a saltwater tank, it will REALLY get trashed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the filled tank weight will be in the neighborhood of 300+ lb.
The stand can support the weight provided the structure is properly enhanced. There are two primary considerations that must be addressed.

1. The entire structure must have adequate stability to resist racking side to side in the 70" direction. The masonite back panel can provide this stability if it is properly secured to the rest of the frame. Any side-to-side motion must be resisted by the back panel. The panel should be screwed to all the verticals and horizontal pieces at approx. 6" or 8" o.c. I am assuming that the back panel is 1/4".  If it is less thick, it should be replaced.
2. The tank weight must be conveyed to the floor. This could be accomplished by centering the tank over the two inner vertical panels (Assuming they are less that 32" apart so the tank spans to extend over each one.) The tank weight must be directly transferred to the floor. Since those panels do not extend to the floor you will need to provide solid feet below each one that passes the weight to the floor.  You can do this with continuous pieces of 2x? wood studs cut to the proper depth.  In addition if there is a gap between the top and there two internal vertical panels that must also be filled with solid material so that the weight doesn't deflect the top

I assume that the finished faces are covered with a plastic veneer that does not absorb water.  You are bound to get it the top wet occasionally and a wood veneer will not age well with sitting water.